# Azure PowerShell SDK: Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Storage.Queues' when Import-Module Az.Storage

Tags: azure, powershell, ubuntu, azure-storage, azure-powershell

I am getting the following error when running: `Import-Module Az.Storage`. I am not what the problem is.

```
PS error: System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The 'New-AzStorageAccount' command was found in the module 'Az.Storage', but the module could not be loaded due to the following error: [Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Storage.Queues, Version=12.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'.]
 For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Storage'.
  ---> System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Storage.Queues, Version=12.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'.
  ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Storage.Queues, Version=12.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'.
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.Bind_LoadAssemblies(ExecutionContext context)
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.Bind(ExecutionContext context, Boolean updateOnly, PSModuleInfo module, Boolean noClobber, Boolean local, Boolean setLocation)
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleManifest(String moduleManifestPath, ExternalScriptInfo manifestScriptInfo, Hashtable data, Hashtable localizedData, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Version minimumVersion, Version maximumVersion, Version requiredVersion, Nullable`1 requiredModuleGuid, ImportModuleOptions& options, Boolean& containedErrors)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 0):

The error ***"*The 'New-AzStorageAccount' command was found in the module 'Az.Storage', but the module could not be loaded due to the following error: [Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Storage.Queues'*"*** usually occurs if the required dependencies are not installed for the `Az.Storage` module.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

```
Import-Module Az.Storage
```

I am able to install the `Az.Storage` module without any error:

[image]

I created an Azure Storage Account by using the below command:

```
New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName RGName -Name StorageAccName -Location Location -SkuName Standard_GRS
```

[image]

[image]

**To resolve the error, please try the below:**

The Azure PowerShell **`Az`** module must be installed in order to use the `Az.Storage` module.

- Check whether you are using the latest version of the **`Az`** module and if not, update the module version:

```
Install-Module -Name az
Update-Module -Name Az
Get-InstalledModule -Name Az
```

[image]

- You can also try updating the **`Az.Storage`** module like below:

```
Update-Module -Name Az.Storage
Get-InstalledModule -Name Az.Storage
```

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, re-install the **`Az`** Module and check.

```
Uninstall-Module -Name az
Install-Module -Name az
```

Check the PowerShell version too. Restart the PowerShell Window after the Uninstall and Install operations.

**Reference:**

[az.storage load errors Azure/azure-powershell · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/12786)